# Kendo upload is not a part of mvc model on submitting

Tags: model-view-controller

I am using, kendo upload for multiple files. Synchronous upload. Have the same property in the mvc model as the kendo upload name, have used  enctype = "multipart/form-data", still my the model property for files is null.Please help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understood the question correctly. Can you show your code and describe what exactly you want?

By the way, you don't need model to get files. You can get your file from `Request.Files` property in your controller. Example:

View:

```
<input type="file" name="files" id="files" />

<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#files").kendoUpload({
            async: {
                saveUrl: "@Url.Action("SaveFiles", "Home")",
                autoUpload: false
            },
            showFileList: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult SaveFiles()
{
    foreach (string key in Request.Files)
    {
        var file = Request.Files[key];
    }
}
```